# Need Help in detmining what design pattern im actually using ? WP7

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, design-patterns, windows-phone-7, mvvm

Hi im quite bad at understaning design patterns i have no idea what one ive implemented, i just build stuff, but hey i want to learn about them so im askign what pattern ive implemented in this project is it mvc ?? or mvvm ??

[image: Screen of Solution explorer]

[image: Screen of MainViewmodel]

in main MainviewModel i only save/load playertoken to isolated storage, the rest is supposed to be dynamic data downloaded on runtime from services and held in the collections decalred in the MainviewModel model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is MVVM - Model View ViewModel. It is close to MVC considering that both the ViewModel and Controller manage model access. However, a ViewModel also performs data manipulations and adapts those for the View, while the controller is generally used to fetch models. A good description of some differences is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel#Pattern_description).